# Como "activar" / "desactivar" un registro mediante Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Después de varios intentos y búsquedas recurro a ustedes por el siguiente problema.
En una tabla tengo un campo de la DB que me da la posibilidad de Activar o No un registro (por ejemplo, para que no se vea).
Tengo un Formulario para actualizar altas, pero necesito como ese acceso directo y no traer todos los datos de la DB para actualizar ese solo campo. Ya que no pueden tener todos los registros el mismo ID es que probé hacerlo con una función y pasándole los parámetros.
Uso Bootstrap para los estilos, de ahí que si está activo, estará en verde la "S" o en rojo la "N".[image: Activar o Desactivar registro] Hasta ahora lo que conseguí es que al hacer click en el botón respectivo me cambia en la DB la "S" por la "N" y viceversa, pero no veo el cambio de la letra ni del formato sin actualizar la página.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
<tr>
    <th class="text-center" width="5px">Activo (S/N)</th>
    <th class="text-center" width="120px">Acción</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text-center"><button onclick="modificar(18,'S')" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">S</button></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="formAlertas.php?id=18" role="button" title="Editar"></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="borraAlertas.php?id=18" role="button" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?');"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text-center"><button onclick="modificar(19,'N')" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">N</button></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="formAlertas.php?id=19" role="button" title="Editar"></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="borraAlertas.php?id=19" role="button" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?');"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**PHP** (activa-alerta.php)

```
<?php 

        $id = $_POST['id'];

        if( $_POST['activo'] === 'N' ) {
            $activo = 'S';
        } else {
            $activo = 'N';
        }
            $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_alertas` SET `activo`='$activo' WHERE `id`='$id'";

            if (mysqli_query( $conn, $sql )) {
                    echo ("exitoso");
                } else {
                    echo ("invalido");
                }

            mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
</table>
<script>
function modificar(idz,acti){
    var elem = $(this);
    var id = idz;
    var activo = acti;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "activa-alerta.php",
        data: {id: id, activo:activo},
        success : function(text,elem){
            if (text == "exitoso"){
                alert(elem);
                esExitoso(elem);
                }
            else {
                esError();
            }
        }
    });

function esExitoso(elem){
   if ( activo === 'S' ) {
        alert(activo);
        elem.removeClass( "btn-danger" );
        elem.html('S');
        elem.addClass( "btn-success" );
    } else {
        alert(activo);
        elem.removeClass( " btn-success" );
        elem.html('N');
        elem.addClass( "btn-danger" );
        }   
    };
function esError(){
        alert('error');
    }; 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Creo no olvidar nada.
Gracias

Comment: En ese caso tendrías que pasar el elemento en la llamada a la función. Por ej: `var elem = $(this); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "activa-alerta.php", data: {id: id, activo:activo}, success : function(text,elem){ if (text == "exitoso"){ esExitoso(elem); } else { esError(); } } }); function esExitoso(elem){ if ( activo === 'S' ) { alert(activo); elem.removeClass( "btn btn-danger" ); // $(this).html('S'); elem.addClass( "btn btn-success" ); } else { alert(activo); elem.removeClass( " btn btn-success" ); //$(this).html('N'); elem.addClass( "btn btn-danger" ); } };`

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano. Edité aquí el código de JQUERY con el que me ha enviado pero sigue igual. Coloqué un alert aquí: if (text == "exitoso"){
                alert(elem);
                esExitoso(elem);
                } para ver que devolvía  --- -- y devuelve 'success', pero cuando se inicializa la varialble elem, ahí si tiene un objeto.

Comment: Puede que estés intentando usar el elemento antes de que el DOM esté cargado. Puedes encerrar todo tu script jQuery dentro de `function`, para asegurar que las funciones no se llamarán sin que el DOM esté listo: **`<script> $(function() {
  // Aquí todo el código JS/jQuery
});</script>`**

Comment: No quisiera robarte tanto tiempo. Pero agregándole eso la consola dice: Uncaught ReferenceError: modificar is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me puse a probar el código y vi que ibas a tener problemas para poder aplicar los cambios.

Te propongo esta solución. Trato de explicarte brevemente los cambios esenciales:

### En el HTML

- Cambié los elementos `button` de este modo: `<button id="btnSi" value="18" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">S</button>`. Como puedes ver, la función no se llama desde dentro del botón pasándole los valores. Le hemos dado un `id` al botón y lo usaremos en jQuery. Eso debido a que del otro modo no se podía recuperar fácilmente el elemento con `this` y mantener todo en el ámbito del DOM era más complicado. También, el `18` está ahora en la etiqueta `value`, que podrás recuperar en jQuery con suma facilidad, como verás más adelante. Y la `S` ya la tenemos en el texto del botón... Lo mismo ocurre con el otro botón.

---

### Javascript/jQuery

- Usaremos el código dentro de `$(function() {`, es la práctica recomendada, para no intentar acceder a los elementos sin que el DOM esté listo.
- Lo que era tu antigua función `modificar(idz,acti)`, se invocará aquí: `$('#btnSi', '#btnNo').on('click', function() {`. Será un listener para los dos botones.
- He mejorado el código Ajax, usando `done` y `fail`, ya que `success` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3.
- En lugar de llamar a la función `esExitoso`, trataremos todo dentro del `done` de Ajax. Por simplicidad, pero si quieres llamar a la función como tenías antes lo puedes hacer. No le vi mucho sentido a hacerlo así.
- La función `esError` también fue sustituida, porque es mejor manejar los errores con el `fail`, propio de la petición Ajax.

Creo que así debería funcionar. Si tienes dudas, puedes comentar.

Espero te sirva.

### JS

```
$(function() {

  $('#btnSi, #btnNo').on('click', function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var activo = elem.text();
    var id = elem.val();
    var url = 'activa-alerta.php';

    var request = $.ajax({
      data: {id: id, activo:activo},
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
      if (text == "exitoso") {
        if (activo == 'S') {
          elem.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
          elem.text('S');
        } else {
          elem.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
          elem.text('N');
        }
      }
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Error de petición: " + textStatus);
    });

  });

});
```

---

### HTML

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" width="5px">Activo (S/N)</th>
    <th class="text-center" width="120px">Acción</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><button id="btnSi" value="18" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">S</button></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="formAlertas.php?id=18" role="button" title="Editar"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="borraAlertas.php?id=18" role="button" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?');"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><button id="btnNo" value="19" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">N</button></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" href="formAlertas.php?id=19" role="button" title="Editar"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="borraAlertas.php?id=19" role="button" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?');"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Estimado @A. Cedano, disculpa la demora pero quise probar todo antes de hablar demás. Tomé la sugerencia y lo probé pero no funciona. Así como está no devuelve nada por consola, ni cambia la db. Pero si a esta linea "$('#btnNo','#btnSi').on(" le borro esto ",'#btnSi'" sì me cambia, pero lo hace solo en ese registro, si quiero cambiar otro ya no, salvo actualizando la pagina. Si borro "'#btnNo'," no funciona. Mi duda surge en el tema de ids que se duplican.

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares hice ese cambio y no llegué a probarlo. Había un error de sintaxis, debes poner el listener así: `$('#btnSi, #btnNo').on('click', function() {` para que funcione con los dos botones. Prueba ahora a ver qué pasa.

Comment: Perfecto. Esta sugerencia ahora funciona. Me queda la duda de los id´s repetidos. Un abrazo Salesiano.

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares me alegro. Pero ¿cuáles son los ids repetidos?

Comment: Tomando como ejemplo la imagen recortada para la pregunta, tengo 1 <button id="btnSi" y 3 <button id="btnNo", aunque la tabla tiene varios registros más,

Comment: Esos no son id duplicados, ya que son distintos. No es lo mismo `btnSi` que `btnNo`. De todos modos, si tú tienes muchos más botones que deben ejecutar el mismo código que esos dos, puedes agruparlos por ejemplo en una misma clase y tener un listener para los botones de esa clase. Así no tienes que poner una lista grande de listeners en el jQuery.

Comment: Buenas tardes @A. Cedano... siguiendo el ejemplo, me funciona todo perfecto pero el problema lo tengo cuando a un mismo botón intento activarlo y desactivarlo varias veces... la celda donde está el botón me cambia el class pero no reinicia los valores del bntSi y btnNo. Acabo de hacer una consulta llamada 'Actualizar Datatable después de AJAX Success'.